# Errors in console when trying to show data from an API request in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm pretty new to Angular. I'm trying to fetch data from my API to show in HTML. The data consists of priceExcludingVAT, VAT and priceIncludingVAT. The problem occurs when i try to show the priceIncludingVAT in HTML. The console keeps saying: TypeError: Cannot read property 'totalInc' of undefined. But the data is visible on the page.

I've tried adding a '?' in the HTML like you see below. But this results in no data being shown at all.
€{{ invoice?.totalInc }}

So what i would like to know is how to display the invoice.totalInc without errors in the console.
Here is a snippet from my code so far. Thanks a lot in advance!!

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'm-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class DashboardComponent {
  url: string = `https://6hdlsw1p9i.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/invoice-styling`;
  items = [];
  invoice: any;

  constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Retrieve data from URL
    this.http.get(this.url).toPromise().then(data => {
      //Loop over every key in the data and push it in the items array
      for (const key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          this.items.push(data[key]);
        }
      }
      console.log('Data now in items array', this.items);

      this.invoice = this.items[1];

      this.handleCalculations()
    })
  }

  handleCalculations(): void {
    //Reset var to prevent bug
    this.invoice.totalEx = 0;
    this.invoice.totalVAT = 0;
    this.invoice.totalInc = 0;

    for (const item of this.invoice.prices) {
      this.invoice.totalEx += item.price;
      this.invoice.totalVAT += item.VAT;
    }

    this.invoice.totalInc = this.invoice.totalEx + this.invoice.totalVAT;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="m-invoice__content">
  <div class="font-2">€{{ invoice?.totalEx }}</div>
  <div class="font-2">€{{ invoice?.totalVAT }}</div>
  <div class="font-2">€{{ invoice.totalInc }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How many elements does the array `items` have? Because you are setting `this.invoice = this.items[1]` which is the second element of the array. If `this.items` only has one element, `this.invoice` will be `undefined`

Comment: @derpirscher the items array has 2 elements. The response and the data. this.invoice is just for readability, but this.items[1] works fine to.

Comment: Furthermore, retrieving your elements from the api is async, but `onNgInit` is synchronous. Thus your component is rendered before the result of the api call has been handled, and thus `this.invoice` is still `undefined` in the first render ...

Comment: You're right. I thought to solve this by adding the '?' to let the HTML wait before trying to render it. Honestly.. i don't know how to use asnyc effectively in this case. Could you educate me?

Comment: No, the `invoice?.totalInc` doesn't "wait" for anything. It just checks whether `invoice` is not null or undefined before it tries to access its properties. If `invoice` is null or undefined, it just returns undefined (instead of throwing and error) [optional chahaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation! But i still do not understand how i can solve the problem.

Comment: You could for instance make use of the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) there are plenty of examples on the web and even on stackoverflow